# The called batch script not returning to the calling batch script

Tags: batch-file

I am calling a batch script (say B.bat) from within another batch script (A.bat). However, once B.bat finishes execution, the execution doesnt seem to return to A.bat, as the batch file remains in the 'Executing' stage after that.
Please see the code below:

Code:

```
Set Scanners_Folder=%CD%
echo %Scanners_Folder%
cd "D:\XYZ\bin"
B.bat && echo B.bat succeeded!!
echo DEF
```

Output:

```
<Current_directory>
<logs from B.bat>
startup.bat succeeded!!
```

After this it does not seem go to the next line of the code in A.bat, which in this case is "echo DEF".
Could anyone help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

use call:

```
Set Scanners_Folder=%CD%
echo %Scanners_Folder%
cd "D:\XYZ\bin"
( call B.bat ) && echo B.bat succeeded!!
echo DEF
```